# Oracle: where can I query java grants?

Tags: java, oracle, sql-grant

I need to check the current user's java grants, something similar to what has been set by:

> dbms_java.grant_permission('SCOTT','java.net.SocketPermission','*','connect');

Can this be done without system privs from the current account?  If I need to do it with system privs, where should I look?

10gR2, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should show up in the DBA_JAVA_POLICY and USER_JAVA_POLICY views.

Answer (score -1):

```
begin
  dbms_java.grant_permission(grantee           => 'CALL_RECORDING',
                             permission_type   => 'java.io.FilePermission',
                             permission_name   => 'D:/AES/-',
                             permission_action => 'execute,read,write,delete');
  commit;
end;
```